# JS How to test if a string is only an abbreviation?

Tags: javascript, regex

Any JS Regex expert that could help me return `true` if the word is only an abbreviation or else `false`?

Tried this regex.

```
/([a-z]{1}\.)/gi
```

But it also returns `true` for strings like.

- `A..`
- `A.B`
- `B.BA..`
- `Greg D. Bot`

I'm trying to formulate a regex that could only return `true` for the following:

- `A.B.`
- `A.B.C.`
- `A.B.C.D.`

And so on..

Comment: Maybe you meant `^([a-z]{1}\.)+$`?

Comment: try this /^([a-z]\.)+$/i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dubious definitions of what counts as an abbreviation aside, the rules are need are:

- Anchored to start of string
- Anchored to end of string
- Matches a exactly 1 letter followed by a period any one or more times

So:

```
/^([a-z]\.)+$/i
```

There's no need for it to be global (because you want the entire string to match, not to find matches anywhere inside a string), and there's no need to say `{1}` because that is the default.